# Как сделать меню для мобильного сайта, открывающееся на весь экран?

Tags: javascript, css, вёрстка, меню

Как сделать меню (выпадающий список) для мобильного сайта, которое будет открываться на весь экран, закрывать все, кроме фиксированного хедера сверху?

Самая большая проблема со скроллом. Контейнер, который открывается под этим самым меню, собственно, не скроллится, возникают постоянные проблемы с его высотой, то настолько высокий, что не видно половины записей меню, все ушли под экран, то недотягивает до низа экрана и болтается просто сверху. Плюс ко всему еще и скроллинг вялый.

Comment: JS-ом при открытии меню ставлю oveflow-y: hidden у body, а overflow-y: scroll у контейнера который вылазит из-под меню тем же js-ом)

Comment: Не согласен, т.к. данный прием еще не отточен в мобильных браузерах, и там убирай не убирай oveflow : hidden , все равно будет прокручиваться весь контент...

Comment: Спасибо за ответ) может тогда Вы подскажете как лучше поступить?)

Comment: Покажите пример Вашей проблемы, возможно у Вас там куча ошибок. Возможно у Вас используется абсолютное позиционирование, что крайне нужно аккуратно использовать, + соответственно z-index, что перекрывает часть меню... по хорошему нужно разбираться и видеть код